# How to get my realm file to show in realm browser on MAC?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, realm

Recently I am using `Realm` for my IOS app. Although I googled but I could not get the `Realm` file to see it through Realm browser in my Mac device. Please suggest me where can I get the file to see it. My XCode is 7.3 and swift version 2.2

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to get the file path by printing this

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL
```

Comment: Optional(file:///Users/parallax/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/78E1D2E1-519A-4135-BD21-A799082269B0/data/Containers/Data/Application/BF92BBAE-12D3-41DD-BD57-38C3617EF78C/Documents/default.realm)   ----> I didn't find Library in parallax.

Comment: try going to your finder, press cmd+shift+g, and paste this

/Users/parallax/Library/Developer/CoreSimula‌​tor/Devices/78E1D2E1‌​-519A-4135-BD21-A799‌​082269B0/data/Contai‌​ners/Data/Applicatio‌​n/BF92BBAE-12D3-41DD‌​-BD57-38C3617EF78C/D‌​ocuments/default.rea‌​lm

Comment: Could not find in finder

Comment: did you make any custom configuration? in this case, the realm file might not be default.realm. it would help if you can show some codes on how you initialise your realm.

Comment: @IrtizaKhanNiloy Use `print(realm.configuration.fileURL)` (realm is your Realm instance) instead? Also `Library` directory is invisible by default. To make `Library` visible, please see https://www.maketecheasier.com/view-library-folder-osx/

Comment: Thank you katsumi and koropok